# If the heap is zero-initialized for security, then why is the stack merely uninitialized?

Tags: linux, security, memory

On my Debian GNU/Linux 9 system, when a binary is executed,

- the stack is uninitialized but
- the heap is zero-initialized.

Why?

I assume that zero-initialization promotes security but, if for the heap, then why not also for the stack? Does the stack, too, not need security?

My question is not specific to Debian as far as I know.

Sample C code:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const size_t n = 8;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// UNINTERESTING CODE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
static void print_array(
  const int *const p, const size_t size, const char *const name
)
{
    printf("%s at %p: ", name, p);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) printf("%d ", p[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// INTERESTING CODE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    int a[n];
    int *const b = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    print_array(a, n, "a");
    print_array(b, n, "b");
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a at 0x7ffe118997e0: 194 0 294230047 32766 294230046 32766 -550453275 32713 
b at 0x561d4bbfe010: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The C standard does not ask `malloc()` to clear memory before allocating it, of course, but my C program is merely for illustration. The question is not a question about C or about C's standard library. Rather, the question is a question about why the kernel and/or run-time loader are zeroing the heap but not the stack.

**ANOTHER EXPERIMENT**

My question regards observable GNU/Linux behavior rather than the requirements of standards documents. If unsure what I mean, then try this code, which invokes further undefined behavior (*undefined,* that is, as far as the C standard is concerned) to illustrate the point:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const size_t n = 4;

int main()
{
    for (size_t i = n; i; --i) {
        int *const p = malloc(sizeof(int));
        printf("%p %d ", p, *p);
        ++*p;
        printf("%d\n", *p);
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output from my machine:

```
0x555e86696010 0 1
0x555e86696010 0 1
0x555e86696010 0 1
0x555e86696010 0 1
```

As far as the C standard is concerned, behavior is undefined, so my question does not regard the C standard. A call to `malloc()` need not return the same address each time but, since this call to `malloc()` does indeed happen to return the same address each time, it is interesting to notice that *the memory, which is on the heap, is zeroed each time.*

The stack, by contrast, had not seemed to be zeroed.

I do not know what the latter code will do on your machine, since I do not know which layer of the GNU/Linux system is causing the observed behavior. You can but try it.

**UPDATE**

@Kusalananda has observed in comments:

> For what it's worth, your most recent code returns different addresses and (occasional) uninitialised (non-zero) data when run on OpenBSD. This obviously does not say anything about the behaviour that you are witnessing on Linux.

That my result differs from the result on OpenBSD is indeed interesting. Apparently, my experiments were discovering not a kernel (or linker) security protocol, as I had thought, but a mere implementational artifact.

In this light, I believe that, together, the answers below of @mosvy, @StephenKitt and @AndreasGrapentin settle my question.

See also on Stack Overflow: [Why does malloc initialize the values to 0 in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8029584/1275653) (credit: @bta).

Comment: For what it's worth, your most recent code returns different addresses and (occasional) uninitialised (non-zero) data when run on OpenBSD.  This obviously does _not_ say anything about the behaviour that you are witnessing on Linux.

Comment: Please do not change the scope of your question, and do not try to edit it in order to make answers and comments redundant. In C, the "heap" is nothing else but the memory returned by malloc() and calloc(), and only the latter is zeroing out the memory; the `new` operator in C++ (also "heap") is on Linux just a wrapper for malloc(); the kernel doesn't know nor care what the "heap" is.

Comment: Your second example is simply exposing an artifact of the malloc implementation in glibc; if you do that repeated malloc/free with a buffer larger than 8 bytes, you will clearly see that only the first 8 bytes are zeroed.

Comment: @Kusalananda I see. That my result differs from the result on OpenBSD is indeed interesting. Apparently, you and Mosvy have shown that my experiments were discovering not a kernel (or linker) security protocol, as I had thought, but a mere implementational artifact.

Comment: @thb I believe that this may be a correct observation, yes.

Comment: There's some relevant information in [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8029624) that you might find useful. `malloc()` can get a memory page from the OS that was previously used by a different process (security issue), but your stack memory is exclusively yours.

Comment: @bta Your link is helpful. I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The storage returned by malloc() is **not** zero-initialized. Do not ever assume it is.

In your test program, it's just a fluke: I guess the `malloc()`just got a fresh block off `mmap()`, but don't rely on that, either.

For an example, if I run your program on my machine this way:

```
$ echo 'void __attribute__((constructor)) p(void){
    void *b = malloc(4444); memset(b, 4, 4444); free(b);
}' | cc -include stdlib.h -include string.h -xc - -shared -o pollute.so

$ LD_PRELOAD=./pollute.so ./your_program
a at 0x7ffd40d3aa60: 1256994848 21891 1256994464 21891 1087613792 32765 0 0
b at 0x55834c75d010: 67372036 67372036 67372036 67372036 67372036 67372036 67372036 67372036
```

Your second example is simply exposing an artifact of the `malloc` implementation in glibc; if you do that repeated `malloc`/`free` with a buffer larger than 8 bytes, you will clearly see that only the first 8 bytes are zeroed, as in the following sample code.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const size_t n = 4;
const size_t m = 0x10;

int main()
{
    for (size_t i = n; i; --i) {
        int *const p = malloc(m*sizeof(int));
        printf("%p ", p);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            printf("%d:", p[j]);
            ++p[j];
            printf("%d ", p[j]);
        }
        free(p);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x55be12864010 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 0:1 
0x55be12864010 0:1 0:1 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 1:2 
0x55be12864010 0:1 0:1 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 2:3 
0x55be12864010 0:1 0:1 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4 3:4
```

Comment: Well, yes, but this is why I have asked the question here rather than on Stack Overflow. My question was not about the C standard but about the way modern GNU/Linux systems typically link and load binaries. Your LD_PRELOAD is humorous but answers another question than the question I had meant to ask.

Comment: I'm happy I made you laugh, but your assumptions and prejudices aren't funny at all. On a "modern GNU/Linux system", binaries are typically loaded by a dynamic linker, which is running constructors from dynamic libraries before getting to the main() function from your program. On your very Debian GNU/Linux 9 system, both malloc() and free() will be called more than once before the main() function from your program, even when not using any preloaded libraries.

Answer (score 27):

Regardless of how the stack is initialised, you’re not seeing a pristine stack, because the C library does a number of things before calling `main`, and they touch the stack.

With the GNU C library, on x86-64, execution starts at the [_start](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/start.S;h=24d59159a9b46e3edd548bfd2f1b1924c6c2eb29;hb=HEAD#l58) entry point, which calls [`__libc_start_main`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/libc-start.c;hb=04277e02d7f54d3582bebcf8386b317018cd5e1d#l129) to set things up, and the latter ends up calling `main`. But before calling `main`, it calls a number of other functions, which causes various pieces of data to be written to the stack. The stack’s contents aren’t cleared in between function calls, so when you get into `main`, your stack contains leftovers from the previous function calls.

This only explains the results you get from the stack, see the other answers regarding your general approach and assumptions.

Comment: Note that by the time `main()` is called, initialization routines may very well have modified memory returned by `malloc()` - especially if C++ libraries are linked in.  Assuming the "heap" is initialized to anything is a really, really bad assumption.

Comment: Your answer together with the Mosvy's settle my question. The system unfortunately allows me *to accept* only one of the two; otherwise, I would accept both.

Answer (score 21):

In both cases, you get *uninitialized* memory, and you can't make any assumptions about its contents.

When the OS has to apportion a new page to your process (whether that's for its stack or for the arena used by `malloc()`), it guarantees that it won't expose data from other processes; the usual way to ensure that is to fill it with zeros (but it's equally valid to overwrite with anything else, including even a page worth of `/dev/urandom` - in fact some debugging `malloc()` implementations write non-zero patterns, to catch mistaken assumptions such as yours).

If `malloc()` can satisfy the request from memory already used and released by this process, its contents won't be cleared (in fact, the clearing is nothing to do with `malloc()` and it can't be - it has to happen before the memory is mapped into your address space).  You may get memory that has previously been written by your process/program (e.g. before `main()`).

In your example program, you're seeing a `malloc()` region that hasn't yet been written by this process (i.e. it's direct from a new page) and a stack that has been written to (by pre-`main()` code in your program).  If you examine more of the stack, you'll find it's zero-filled further down (in its direction of growth).

If you really want to understand what's happening at the OS level, I recommend that you bypass the C Library layer and interact using system calls such as `brk()` and `mmap()` instead.

Comment: Your answer is good as far as it goes, +1, but my question has lent itself to misunderstanding. I have edited the question to clarify that I am not asking not about the requirements of the C standard (if I were asking that, I would ask on Stack Overflow) but about the observed behavior of GNU/Linux systems.

Comment: A week or two ago, I tried a different experiment, calling `malloc()` and `free()` repeatedly. Though nothing requires `malloc()` to reuse the same storage recently freed, in the experiment, `malloc()` did happen to do that. It happened to return the same address each time, but also nulled the memory each time, which I had not expected. This was interesting to me. Further experiments have led to today's question.

Comment: Uhh, if you call a low enough level call it is indeed guaranteed to be filled with zeros.

Comment: If it interests you, I have added the second experiment to the question.

Comment: @thb, Perhaps I'm not being clear enough - most implementations of `malloc()` do absolutely *nothing* with the memory they hand you - it's either previously-used, or freshly-assigned (and therefore zeroed by the OS).  In your test, you evidently got the latter.  Similarly, the stack memory is given to your process in the cleared state, but you don't examine it far enough to see parts your process hasn't yet touched.  Your stack memory *is* cleared before it's given to your process.

Comment: @Joshua, can you cite a standard that says that dynamic allocations need to be zero-filled?  Anonymous `mmap()` is zero-initialised, but I can't find a corresponding guarantee for `sbrk()` - and `malloc()` may use either, or indeed a combination of both.

Comment: @TobySpeight: brk and sbrk are obsoleted by mmap. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/brk.html says LEGACY right at the top.

Comment: @Joshua, that page says "*The use of `malloc()` is now preferred*", i.e. a higher-level library function, rather than recommending alternative system calls.  `malloc()` *implementations* aren't really subject to that recommendation, almost by definition.

Comment: On the other hand, `malloc` is deliberately a swappable component. Implementing `malloc` w/o any legacy functions pretty much implies `mmap`.

Comment: [Linux manpages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html) note "4.3BSD; SUSv1, marked LEGACY in SUSv2, removed in POSIX.1-2001" but not deprecated in Linux and [malloc on Linux still uses it in some situations](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15277538). [FreeBSD manpages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=brk) say "The brk() and sbrk() functions are legacy interfaces from before the advent of modern virtual memory management. They are deprecated and not present on the arm64 or riscv architectures. The mmap(2) interface should be used to allocate pages instead."

Comment: If you need initialized memory using `calloc` might be an option (instead of `memset`)

Comment: @thb and Toby: fun fact: new pages from the kernel are often lazily allocated, and merely copy-on-write mapped to a shared zeroed page.  This happens for `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` unless you use `MAP_POPULATE` as well.  New stack pages are hopefully backed by fresh physical pages and wired up  (mapped in the hardware page tables, as well as the kernel's pointer/length list of mappings) when growing, because normally new stack memory is  being written when touched for the first time.  But yes, the kernel must avoid leaking data somehow, and zeroing is the cheapest and most useful.

Answer (score 9):

Your premise is wrong.

What you describe as 'security' is really **confidentiality**, meaning that no process may read another processes memory, unless this memory is explicitly shared between these processes. In an operating system, this is one aspect of the *isolation* of concurrent activities, or processes.

What the operating system is doing to ensure this isolation, is whenever memory is requested by the process for heap or stack allocations, this memory is either coming from a region in physical memory that is filled whith zeroes, or that is filled with junk that is coming from **the same process**.

This ensures that you're only ever seeing zeroes, or your own junk, so confidentiality is ensured, and **both** heap **and** stack are 'secure', albeit not necessarily (zero-)initialized.

You're reading too much into your measurements.

Comment: The question's Update section now explicitly references your illuminating answer.